# How would I solve this nonlinear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would I solve this ODE, assuming f > 0 $\forall x$:

$$\begin{equation}
f^2(x) + xf(x) f'(x) = c f'(x)
\end{equation}$$

Comment: This is just separation of variables no? I feel like I said this yesterday.

Comment: There wasn't an $f'(x)$ on the right hand side. Could you maybe do it with a term on the right? I think its not so trivial

Comment: Why can't you isolate $f'(x)$ then?

Comment: Thats what I did, but Wolfram Alpha (as a check) says a lambert W function is involved. I wasn't sure how to resolve that.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+f%5E2+%2B+x+f%28x%29+f%27%28x%29+%3D+c+f%27%28x%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for substitution really
$$
f^2 + xff' = cf' \implies f + xf'-\frac{c}{f}f' = 0
$$
Now you can see
$$
\left(xf\right)' -c\left(\ln f\right)' = 0
$$
You can integrate straight away to yield 
$$
xf -c\ln f + k = 0\tag{*}
$$
Using the sub $ \ln u = \phi $ where $u^{-1} = f\mathrm{e}^{-k/c}$ (skipping a few steps in logic) we find
$$
-\frac{x\mathrm{e}^{k/c}$}{c} = \mathrm{e}^{\phi}\phi 
$$
Taking the lambert function we find
$$
W\left(-\frac{x\mathrm{e}^{k/c}}{c}\right) = \phi = -\ln u^{-1}  = -\ln f + \frac{k}{c} 
$$ now the lhs is just equal to a rearrangement of Eq (*) and thus we get
$$
W\left(-\frac{x\mathrm{e}^{k/c}}{c}\right) = -xf
$$ then you get
$$
f(x) = -\frac{W\left(-\frac{x\mathrm{e}^{k/c}}{c}\right)}{x}
$$
Which matches the output.

Answer (score 2):

change of variable $u = {1 \over f}.$ then $\frac{df}{dx} = -{1 \over u^2} \frac{du}{dx}$ substituting this we get $${1 \over u^2} - {x\over u} \frac{1}{u^2} \frac{du}{dx} =-{c \over u^2}\frac{du}{dx}$$ which simplifies to a linear nonhomogeneous equation$$\frac{dx}{du} = \frac{x-cu}{u} = {x \over u} - c$$

we will try the variation of parameters. try $$x = Au$$ where $A$ as a function of $u$ to be determined. A satisfies $$u\frac{dA}{du} + A = A - c $$ which has solution $$ A = B - c\ln u,\   x = Bu - c u\ln u$$ where $B$ is an arbitrary constant.

going back to the original variable, we have $$x = { 1\over f}(B + c  \ln f)$$

hope i did not mess up anything again.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+f%5E2+%2B+x+f%28x%29+f%27%28x%29+%3D+c+f%27%28x%29

Comment: Im trying to resolve that. but it doesnt seem to make sense. There is no unique solution therefore?

Comment: @Drew: It shouldn't be very difficult. Note that it's a Linear ODE.

Comment: @abel, How did you come up with the change of variable $u=1/f$?

Comment: @abel So the solution is imaginary?/ could you fill in the details please?

Comment: Shouldnt there be a du/dx in the second term x/u @abel?

Comment: The form should be $\frac{1}{u^2} - \frac{x}{u^3} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = -\frac{c}{u^2} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$

Comment: @Drew, i will check my work.

Comment: @Drew, can you please check my edited answer.

Comment: @Radz, lucky substitution. there is no systematic way to find a good change of variable. just trial and error.

Comment: still not right my friend

Comment: @Drew, where is the error?

Comment: Dear @abel. Thanks.

Comment: Ps my post is just a compliment to yours. +1.